# What happens if someone overwrites a file after I open it?

Tags: c++, c, file

When I open a file in C, I get a file descriptor, if I had not read it's contents, and then someone modifies the file, will I read the old file or the new file?
Let's say a file has lots of lines, what happens that while reading the file, someone edits the beginning, will this somehow corrupt how my file reads the file?

How do programs don't get corrupted while the file is being read? Is the OS that takes care of this problem? If I can still read the old data, where is this data being stored?

The man page of open, has some information about the internals of open, but it is not very clear to me.

Comment: For sure it doesn't succeed to delete it while it is open.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa In Posix it may be deleted, but an opened file still exist for the processes that has it opened. It's just removed from the directory.

Comment: The C standard library doesn't have a concept of file sharing, and doesn't define what should happen when the same file is being opened a second time. The behavior is implementation-dependent.

Comment: In Windows, an opened file can be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C language standard doesn't acknowledge the existence of other processes nor specify interaction between them and the program (nor does C++). The behaviour depends on the operating system and / or the file system.

Generally, it is safest to assume that file operations are not atomic and therefore accessing a file while another process is editing it would be an example of race condition. Some systems may provide some stricter guarantees.

A general approach to attempt avoiding problems is file locking. The standard C library does not have an API for file locking, but multitasking operating systems generally do.

Answer (score 2):

All this depends heavily on the OS, not at the C++ level. In Windows, for example, opening the file with CreateFile allows you to lock the file for subsequent access. But not at the language level.

You must decide based on the specific OS you work with. There are *no* assumptions; it all depends on the documentation you are provided with.

Generally, C++ level documentation is not much useful at such problems because there can never be a full standard for something so low level as file access (even the fs was only recently added to C++) and there is no point creating 'portable' code on such. You must make it a habit to immerse in the OS specific documentation and libraries.